# Save a subset of a dictionary as a new variable and preserve the original dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, copy, subset

I am importing large JSON files as dictionaries in python. I need to perform operations on one of the keys in the dictionary, which is itself a list. I want to preserve the original imported dictionary (unchanged).

I'm pretty unexperienced with Python but I've read that y = x creates a new variable y that references the same object that x references.... which means that changes made to y will also change the original variable x?

So if I used

```
players =data["Players"]
```

and made changes to the new variable players, would that somehow change the original dict? I've tested this and don't see the changes carried across, but I'm concerned I'm missing something.

Do I need to create a copy of the key to ensure that I'm preserving the original dictionary? And since a list is a compound object, do I need to create a deepcopy so that the objects inside aren't references either? 
I.e., either :

```
players = data["Players"].copy()
players = copy.deepcopy(data["Players"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about using copy/deepcopy if you specify a specific key of the dict.

You can easily verify using [id()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)

For example:

```py
data = {
    "Players": ["p1", "p2", "p3"]
}

# creates new object - not y = x
players = data["Players"]

# references same object - yes y = x
players2 = data

print(f'data id     -> {id(data)}  \nplayers2 id -> {id(players2)} \nplayers id  -> {id(players)}')
```

Results (notice data and players2 have the same id):

```
data id     -> 140253164993728  
players2 id -> 140253164993728 
players id  -> 140253164186432
```

Comment: thank you this is very helpful. And the id() check will be a sanity maintainer for me. I find the y=x relation so unintuitive for some reason.